# If I have an Azure App Service Plan with no App Services, is the underlying VM Stopped?

Tags: azure

I set up an S1 Azure App Service plan yesterday and have not added any app services yet.

When I look at the App Service Plan properties, using the new Portal, I see the Usage Quota has a message "No Available Data" and the Estimated spend has a message "Billing data will arrive as you accrue costs"

Of course If I create an App Service for a few days I would expect billing to start.  If I then delete the app service so that there are none. Will billing on the plan be suspended?

i.e does the underlying virtual machine stop?

This relates to [my question about whether I can pause the plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780331/how-do-i-pause-an-azure-app-service-plan).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter if you have or not any web app attached to the plan, Microsoft will bill you the Service Plan, because you have reserved an instance with the characteristics described in the Service Plan.

For additional info on how plans and their billing work, check my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308528/web-apps-with-app-service-plan/42308616) and the answer.

Answer (score -5):

Microsoft Azure has their own customer support forums and toll-free customer service phone numbers.  You should really be availing yourself of those *official* resources for something like billing questions.

Comment: I have changed the question to make it a technical one.

Comment: Yup.  That's exactly why you should be talking to the people that are going to take your money, instead of the internet at large.  The Azure team is uniquely qualified to answer questions about how much you are going to be charged for their services.

Comment: i guess the question is kind of irrelevant since a service plan with no apps may as well be deleted.

Comment: Why is this a marked answer? It's a comment to contact Azure technical support. Not an answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Azure billing is so complicated that it seems a technical subject , indeed it is taught as part of a technical course I am doing on Pluralsight. However the idea of having a plan without an app to go with it is a bit contrived. If I did it and got charged I would have to haggle with Microsoft not SO, thus I accepted the answer.