# Web Apps with App service plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview), and specially this paragraph:

> The **SKU** and **Scale** of the App Service plan determines the cost and not the number of apps hosted in it.

Can I create as many Web Apps as I need into the same resource group with the same App Service Plan?

For instance, I have a RG named *S1-Resources* and a S1 App Service Plan. If I create for instance 3 Web Apps into that RG linking them to the App Service, Will I be charged  $0.10/hr for each Web App?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a good explanation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview

Basically yes you can save money by hosting multiple apps in one app service plan - if you scale this plan to 2 instances, and you have 2 web sites running, they will both run on both instances.

Comment: Thank you Rusell

So, if I deploy many web apps under a app service plan is like if I was running  all in only one "VM"? does it is?

Comment: I will change now the question: what's the difference between web app and instance?

Comment: Consider the web app as the a placeholder to host your app code and configuration in.  An instance would be one running copy of this (and other web apps in the same service plan)

Comment: I have marked as the correct answer. Than you @Russell 
A Microsoft Support Engineer confirmed that.

Comment: Are you sure they don't refer to a instance of a running VM when the say "instance"? I am confused - when do we refer to the instance of the app and when to an instance of a VM used to run the app?