# App Services S1 Features - Web App On Linux + MySQL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking to deploy a "Web App On Linux + MySQL" but am not sure what some of the features of the S1 Standard pricing tier mean.

"Up to 10 instance(s)" - What constitutes an instance?

"5 Slots" for "Web app staging" - What does this mean?

I'm trying to decide whether or not I need the S1 Standard offering or if B1 Basic is sufficient for my needs. Appreciate any insight from people better versed in Azure than I am.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is off-topic, as it's really very broad and not something that can be objectively answered (regarding scaling and choosing a tier size). You'd have to benchmark to see which tier (basic vs standard) is right for you. And each has their own amount of disk space, memory, etc. And instances are instances of your web app, when you scale out. Different tiers have different scalability. It's all in the docs, along with info on staging slots.

Answer (score 0):

> "Up to 10 instance(s)" - What constitutes an instance?

You could refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview).

When you create an app in App Service, it is put into an App Service plan. When the app runs, it runs on all the VM instances configured in the App Service plan. If multiple apps are in the same App Service plan, they all share the same VM instances. If you have multiple deployment slots for an app, all deployment slots also run on the same VM instances. If you enable diagnostic logs, perform backups, or run WebJobs, they also use CPU cycles and memory on these VM instances.

In this way, the App Service plan is the scale unit of the App Service apps. If the plan is configured to run five VM instances, then all apps in the plan run on all five instances. If the plan is configured for autoscaling, then all apps in the plan are scaled out together based on the autoscale settings.

For S1 standard, you could autoscale your app run 10 VM instances.

You also could could refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308528/web-apps-with-app-service-plan).

> "5 Slots" for "Web app staging" - What does this mean?

You could refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing).

When you deploy your web app, web app on Linux, mobile back end, and API app to App Service, you can deploy to a separate deployment slot instead of the default production slot when running in the Standard or Premium App Service plan mode. Deployment slots are actually live apps with their own hostnames.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.