# How to change basic to standard tier in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My app deployed in Azure with basic tier having 10GB space. Now it showing the usage warning error in Server. So I want change the scale from basic to standard. Then which instance size should choose having ( Small-1 core, Medium-2cores and Large- 4 cores) ? Also while saving following notifications are showing

1. In Standard mode, if a web app is stopped, billing continues, and changing the scaling for an app affects other apps. Are you sure you want to continue?
2. This will scale the following web apps in the East US 2 region. This can take several minutes to complete. Your web apps will keep running during the process.

please help

Comment: related to - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34780331/5255018

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, here is a [table with App Service sizes](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/app-service/) in which you can see that the *Standard* size has **50GB** and the *Premium* has **500GB** of disk space.

To answer your other questions:

1. The reality is that you pay for the **App Service Plan**, each plan can host dozens of Apps. Think of it as a Platform running all the time that hosts your Apps, if you stop one App, the Platform is still running (because you might have other Apps running on it), and thus, you are still charged for it.
2. Like I said, because what you pay is the App Service Plan, scaling the Plan will automatically **scale all the Apps** contained in it, that's the reason of the second message.

Think of the App Service Plan as a server in which you run your Apps, the moment you delete all the Apps in the Plan, the Plan stops billing, but as long as you have at least one App (running or stopped) in it, it will keep charging.

Comment: The region East US 2 will not affect other region i.e. East US ?  Can I downgrade later from standard to basic tier?

Comment: An App Service on East US 2 does not affect an App Service in East US, they are separate services. And yes, you can always downgrade.