# How to reduce costs with Azure IoT Suite?

Tags: azure, iot

I started a IoT monitoring solution with azureiotsuite.com. This provisioned multiple services on my Azure account, which have dramatically increased the compute costs. The image shows all that have been provisioned for the suite:

[image]

All of these services have been provisioned within the same resource group. I would like to experiment further with the IoT suite, but not have things running while I'm not working on it.

**Edit**

Azure provisions two plans with Event Hubs, IoT Hubs, multiple storage and stream analytics instances. Although impressive, it is costly.

Can I stop or deallocate these services easily, or is the best course of action to provision and delete every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those -plan services are Azure App Service Plans. These determine how much resources you get for the Web Apps running on them. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview):

> Your App Service plan can scale form Free and Shared SKUs to Basic, Standard, and Premium SKUs giving you access to more resources and features along the way.
>
> If your App Service plan is set to Basic SKU or higher you can control the size and scale count of the VMs.

They can be scaled up/out easily. I do not know what plan is used now but maybe you can scale down? See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/ for the available tiers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale on how to scale up or down.

Scaling down might give a performance degradation but if it is just for experiments and not used for production I would give it a try. But beware: some parts of the IoT Suite might require a minimum tier of the App Service Plan that is used. (I have no experience with the IoT Suite)

You can't pause an App Service Plan, only option is to scale down or delete. See also [How do I pause an Azure App Service Plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780331/how-do-i-pause-an-azure-app-service-plan).

Comment: Apparently the components of the suite do not scale down, except that I was able to reduce the number of simulated devices reporting. I added specifics and corrections based on your answer.