# How to Pause or Stop Azure APP service in Night/Day Time when not required?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to put app to sleep during night time anymore?
I have the app service setting NOT on "Always On", but this setting is not respected.

The bills used to be twice as much as they are now, because in past they app set itself to sleep. How do I know this? The service hours are now around 730 (that's a full month). Is Azure no more "Pay-As -You-Go?"

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780331/how-do-i-pause-an-azure-app-service-plan. This may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Joonas**, There was never an option to put the app to sleep in **Azure Web Apps**. The only way to ensure that you are not getting billed is to **Scale down** the corresponding *App Service Plan* of the web app to **FREE** tier.

You can configure scale settings based on a specific schedule so that the app service plan can be scaled up.

**Always On** is a setting used to keep your app up and running at all times. Assume that you have 10 web apps hosted on a server, out of which 8 are your dev or least used sites, while the other 2 are busy sites accessed throughout the day. In such a scenario you don't want the dev sites to be running at all times as they will hold system resources. The **Always On** feature is handy in such scenarios. You can set **Always On** to true for the 2 busy sites and **false** for the other 8 sites.

> Check the number of **App Service Plans** in your subscription and
>   also their pricing tier. This will help you understand the costs. In
>   Azure App Service, you get billed for the **App Service Plan** and not
>   the Web App.

This image should help you understand App Service Plan
[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure of this? Because my bills are almost twice the amount TODAY than they used to be in 2016. And I didn't change any settings as I recall.. I see that the service hours used to be much less. Now it's always running.

Comment: yes. This is how it works. I would recommend you to compare the older bills with current ones and check what was the pricing tier of the app service plan. You can create a billing ticket via Azure Portal. It is anyways free. Azure Billing support will clarify if there are any discrepancies.

Comment: Azure customer service is a mess. Subscription transfer from one person to another took us like 7 months. Crazy. And now I can't see my invoices from year 2016 to compare because apparently it isn't supported. Oh well.

Comment: I will still urge you to contact them to see if they can provide you the older bills. If nothing works, then you may want to provide a feedback on this here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing

Comment: Also I am surprised that subscription transfers took so much time. Ping me if there is anything that I can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer from [this official FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/):

> Am I charged for apps while they are in stopped state?
>
> ***Yes. Rates listed apply to apps in stopped state. Please delete apps that are not in use or update tier to Free to avoid charges.***

Comment: So what is the "Always On" button for? Why would someone deliberately shoot themselves in the leg and make their app go through a cold start?

Comment: web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time, enabling  [Always On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure) can keep the app loaded all the time.

Comment: Why would one want them to be unloaded if they paid for it?

Comment: Because the memory footprint of the idle app could be put to good use (i.e. could be used by another app which does get traffic). If you're serious about one particular app, just enable the Always On feature and it will never get unloaded. Has nothing to do with billing, you get billed for the App Service Plan, not individual Web Apps.

Comment: The service hours are now around 730 (that's a full month). When I was charged less, the service hours were also fewer. Is Azure no more "Pay-As -You-Go?"

Comment: Azure App Service was always billed based on pricing tier of app service plan. As I said, unless you do a compare of the older and the current bills, there is no sure way of saying what is the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Would it make sense to check "Always On" then? (Since it doesn't affect costs)? I only have 1 service.