# How to configure an app service that only needs to be up-and-running a few days per month

Tags: azure, .net-core, automation, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I have a Web API Core app that only needs to run for a few days per month.  I'd like to only have it incurring costs in Azure for the few days that I run it per month.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pause an Azure App Service Plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780331/how-do-i-pause-an-azure-app-service-plan)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you "Stop" the App Service, you will be charged as per your plan. So you can have the App Service in the Free Tier. But you cannot have the features like Custom Domain, Backups etc.